# Phonegap Build - Google Expanding APK Files

Tags: cordova, google-play, apk, phonegap-build

I have been successfully developing apps with Phonegap Build and normal phonegap cli, however I now have an app that exceeds the 50MB limit for initial APK upload to google play. Is there anyone that can offer assistance in the right direction for creating the expanding APK? It will contain audio files.

Answer (score 1):

Current Google play documents indicate a 100MB limit and that you can expand on that with expansion files ;

https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html